# Generate an OpenAPI YAML specification of a Spring Application in a GitLab CI step

Tags: java, spring, automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am looking for a way to generate the OpenAPI specifiaction as a YAML file of a Spring application by using the GitLab CI. I want to use the YAML as an artifact and reuse it for other purposes. Has anyone find a way to do so?